# XAML Binding to dynamic nested objects

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a response from a JSON API and map it in my Code to an Object. 
The Object Structure looks like this:

```
public class A {
    public B b;
    public C c;
    public D d;
}
public class B{
    public string a;
    public string b;
}
...
public class D{
    public F[] f;
}
public class F{
    public string c;
    public string d;
    public string e;
}
```

I set up my Binding to an `Observable Collection <A> aCollection` and it's working fine. I have some Objects of A and can access all members like this.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding aCollection}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding b.a, TargetNullValue='-'}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding c.a, TargetNullValue='-'}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

But I don't know how I can access the Array F[] and the members of F. Also I don't know in advance how large the array will be.

What I want to achieve is to display every entry in the array in relation to the containing Object A.

Hope this question makes sense.

Comment: What are you wanting to do with the Array F[]? List each value in a label? Something else?

Comment: Yes, they are all String values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind Array data into every cell in listview .According to your code you can modify like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding aCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding b.a, TargetNullValue='-'}"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding c.a, TargetNullValue='-'}"/>

                    //***
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding d.F}">
                          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                             <DataTemplate>
                               <ViewCell>
                                  <StackLayout>
                                     <Entry Text="{Binding c}"/>
                                     <Entry Text="{Binding d}"/>
                                     <Entry Text="{Binding e}"/>
                                  </StackLayout>
                               </ViewCell>
                             </DataTemplate>
                          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    //***

                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

use listview contain a listview to show data etc.And your class D change to

```
 public class {
    public List<F> f{ get; set; }
 }
```

Not sure whether is you want,hope to be useful.

Comment: I came up with this solution myself yesterday. But it seems to lack performance :X Is there another view possibility which can use Data from Array?

Comment: ListView also can,just like this:listView.ItemsSource = new string[]{  "mono",  "monodroid","monotouch","monorail","monodevelop"},refer to this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding#ItemsSource

Comment: Array length is not variable,when you use modle it is not recommended,So this situation,Array can be saw as  a **Value Types**,Array is same as the string,they are all a Struct ,it has not a container's function,However,List can do that.